# Configure SQL Server drivers on IBM power 9

Tags: sql-server, odbc, suse, mssql-jdbc

MSODBCSQL driver is not being able to installed since it is IBM Power 9 server.

```
/home/msodbcsql-11.0.2260.0 # ./install.sh verify      

Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server Installation Script
Copyright Microsoft Corp.

Starting install for Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server

Checking for 64 bit Linux compatible OS ................................. FAILED
Checking required libs are installed ............................... NOT CHECKED
unixODBC utilities (odbc_config and odbcinst) installed ............ NOT CHECKED
unixODBC Driver Manager version 2.3.0 installed .................... NOT CHECKED
unixODBC Driver Manager configuration correct ...................... NOT CHECKED
Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server already installed .......... NOT CHECKED

See /tmp/msodbcsql.12877.31377.3703/install.log for more information about installation failures.
```

I need the link of SQL Server drivers on IBM power 9.

Comment: Have you solved this since?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server isn't running on Power 9. On IBM Power only  MariaDB, MySQL, DB2 etc. are running